# Creating pthread in web worker causes an error "Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL'"

Tags: emscripten

I am porting some multithreaded C++ program into WebAssembly.
When I executed the compiled code using importScripts in a web worker, the following error occurred.

```
Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

The reason of this error was because either Module["mainScriptUrlOrBlob"].
(Since it is on the web worker, document.currentScript is not defined.)

I assigned the generated JS file to Module["mainScriptUrlOrBlob"] in pre.js, then the error disappeared but a thread did not run.

Is assigning the generated JS file to Module["mainScriptUrlOrBlob"] wrong?
How can I run threads from web worker?

My environment is,

- macOS 10.14.6
- emcc lateset-upstream

  - emcc 1.38.40
  - clang 10.0.0
- Google Chrome 76.0.3809.87

Thanks.